# Cisco Catalyst 2950

Tags: cisco, switch

Could anyone tell me latest version of IOS that this switch can run?

I can't find any definitive answers anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It's **12.1(22)EA14**.

This was the first hit on Google, but Cisco's website is a little bit hard to navigate, right?

Just go [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps628/index.html), then "Download Software", select your model, then iOS.

Comment: http://www.cisco.com/cisco/software/navigator.html - or the link that Yves provided, is your best bet. Cisco support is also fairly good about providing download instructions to get you the latest software you're licensed for under contract.